# why my python program is failing for 2 test cases?

Tags: python

I have below code to find the winner based on winner:

```
def minion_game(string):
    vowels = 'AEIOU'
    kevin = 0
    stuart = 0
    n = len(string)

    for i in range(n):
        if string[i] in vowels:
            kevin += n - i
        else:
            stuart += n - i

    if kevin > stuart:
        winner = "Kevin"
        score = kevin
    elif kevin < stuart:
        winner = "Stuart"
        score = stuart
    else:
        winner = "Draw"
        score = kevin

    print(winner, score)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    minion_game(s)
```

Below is the user story that I got from hacker rank [website](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-minion-game/problem?isFullScreen=true)

```
Kevin and Stuart want to play the 'The Minion Game'.

Game Rules

Both players are given the same string,
.
Both players have to make substrings using the letters of the string

.
Stuart has to make words starting with consonants.
Kevin has to make words starting with vowels.
The game ends when both players have made all possible substrings.

Scoring
A player gets +1 point for each occurrence of the substring in the string

.

For Example:
String
= BANANA
Kevin's vowel beginning word = ANA
Here, ANA occurs twice in BANANA. Hence, Kevin will get 2 Points.
```

I have below queries:

```
- The code works fine in IDE, and for the first time when I started to execute the code in hacker rank it was throwing error. I was returning "score" and name("Kevin", "Stuart"). Then I replaced "return" with print(), and then the code passed. Why?

- There are 15 test cases, but 2 of them failed. Not sure why. I do not have enough "heckos" to know the details of the test cases that failed.
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You are failing 2 test cases when the scores are equal.

in your code you are printing `'Draw Kevin's score'`

```
else:
    winner = "Draw"
    score = kevin
```

You just need to print 'Draw' when the scores match. I have modified your code.

```
def minion_game(string):
    vowels = 'AEIOU'
    kevin = 0
    stuart = 0
    n = len(string)

    for i in range(n):
        if string[i] in vowels:
            kevin += n - i
        else:
            stuart += n - i

    if kevin > stuart:
        print("Kevin",kevin)
    elif kevin < stuart:
        print("Stuart",stuart)
    else:
        print("Draw")
```

[image]